# How can i solve this Pivot Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I got this error when pivoting this table.

**ERROR**

> Column 'Properties.userAccount.accountUsername' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: im using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: You are doing an aggegrate `COUNT(..)`, but not grouping by any column. Try to add `GROUP BY  uac.accountUsername, YEAR(prop.soldDate)`.

Comment: when you use count, sum, ... u must use Group by...

Comment: oh ok thanks.. after which part i do the group by pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do instead :

```
SELECT uac.accountUsername,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(prop.soldDate) = 2017 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2017],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(prop.soldDate) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2018]
FROM [Properties].[userAccount] uac JOIN 
     [Properties].[property] prop
     ON uac.accountId = prop.accountId
GROUP BY uac.accountUsername;
```

For your `PIVOT` version you just missed to include non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY` clause which are `uac.accountUsername, YEAR(prop.soldDate)`.

So it should be included :

```
WITH AnnualSales (Username, YearOfSale, Properties) AS (
     SELECT uac.accountUsername, YEAR(prop.soldDate), COUNT(prop.propertyId)
     FROM [Properties].[userAccount] uac JOIN 
           [Properties].[property] prop
           ON (uac.accountId = prop.accountId)
     GROUP BY uac.accountUsername, YEAR(prop.soldDate)
)
SELECT *
FROM AnnualSales PIVOT 
    (SUM(Properties) FOR YearOfSale IN ([2017],[2018])
    ) AS pvt
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to use a Pivot

Comment: What is `SUM(Properties)`?  Also, what is the point of aggregating inside the pivot?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PIVOT` syntax is off:

```
SELECT
    accountUsername,
    year,
    [2017],
    [2018]
FROM
(
    SELECT uac.accountUsername, YEAR(prop.soldDate) AS year
    FROM [Properties].[userAccount] uac
    INNER JOIN [Properties].[property] prop
        ON uac.accountId = prop.accountId
) t
PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR YearOfSale IN ([2017],[2018])) AS pvt
ORDER BY 1;
```